# Is this modified cleanedup function correct?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

So I'm new to python, and I was hoping if I could get some insight towards my cleaned up function. My cleanedup is suppose to keep not only letters but numbers, and certain symbols like '@' and '_'. Here is my code.

```
def cleanedup(s):
    alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    digits = '0123456789'
    cleantext = ''
    for character in s.lower():
        if character in alphabet, digits, or characters == '@', '_':
            cleantext += character
        else:
            cleantext += ' '
    return cleantext
```

I was hoping to see if this function is correct or if it needs some adjusting. If there is a need for some adjusting, I hope it is nothing far different from what I have above. Thank you.

Comment: Please, do try to run it. Python intrepreter will automatically spit out errors in case there are any syntax issues. Logical fixes can be done as a second step.

Answer (score 1):

`character in alphabet, digits, or characters == '@', '_'` is not a valid Python expression.  I'm surprised you're not getting an error.  The correct way to express this would be

```
if character in alphabet or character in digits or character in ('@', '_'):
```

A better way would be to condense all the allowed characters into a single data structure, then compare the characters against that:

```
from string import acii_lowercase, digits

allowed = set(ascii_lowercase + digits + '@_')

def cleanedup(s):
    return ''.join(c if c in allowed else ' ' for c in s.lower())
```

`''.join` is another way of combining many strings, that doesn't create additional strings in the process.

A `set` is a data structure like a list that works more like a mathematical set.  It's faster to look up whether or not an object is in a set than it is to for a list.

A more advanced way of doing what you want would be to use regular expressions:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile("[^a-z0-9@_]")  # All characters that are not a-z, 0-9, _, and @

def cleanedup(s):
    return pattern.sub(' ', s.lower())
```